# How to configure crontab to run Django command?

Tags: python, django, cron, debian

I run a Debian 10 system have the following shell file named "update.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
cd home/user/djangoprojet
source /env/bin/activate
python manage.py update
```

I run a root user and set "chmod +x update.sh".

When I run "home/user/djangoprojet/update.sh", executing the script works perfectly.

I now used "crontab -e" to run the script every minute:

```
* * * * * home/user/djangoprojet/update.sh > testcron.log
```

However, the script is not executed. When I run "grep CRON /var/log/syslog", I get the following result, which indicates that crontab runs:

> Jan 30 15:08:01 vServer CRON[22036]: (root) CMD > (home/user/djangoprojet/update.sh > testcron.log) Jan 30 15:08:01
> vServer CRON[22035]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

The "testcron.log" file, located in the root directory, is empty - although the script would generate an output, if it ran.

Somewhere on StackExchange I also found to execute this command

```
/bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; home/user/djangoprojet/update.sh </dev/null)"
```

which works perfectly.

How can I configure crontab correctly such that my script runs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I now found the solution: I need to use "/home/" instad of "home/" everywhere